# How to do paging in MithrilJS?

Tags: javascript, pagination, mithril.js

I have a dataset of about 50 items in-memory and am attempting to create a pager for this dataset, but I'm unsure how to do this.

I'm using a custom filter function to filter the results, and that works fine, but somehow I need to get the number of pages out.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

[Mithril Infinite](https://github.com/ArthurClemens/mithril-infinite) is a versatile Mithril component for handling potentially large collections of items. It's primary purpose is as a potentially infinite scrolling list, but its Github pages also features [a pagination demo](http://arthurclemens.github.io/mithril-infinite/index.html#/paging).

Pagination shouldn't be a difficulty per se. At its simplest pagination requires a stateful index indicating the page to display, and a method for splitting a list into sub-lists to represent pages.

The key is a good reducer function to create a list of pages out of our initial list of items:

```
// The initially empty collection of pages is the first argument.
// The function executes once for each item in a provided list like forEach & map.
function paginate( pages, item, index ){
  // Modulo (%) is the remainder of x after division by y
  // A result of 0 means a multiple. 
  // So if pageLength is 6, we would create a new page at 0, 6, 12, 18, etc...
  if( index % pageLength === 0 )
    pages.push( [] )

  // Push the item onto the last page
  pages[ pages.length - 1 ].push( item )

  // Return the pages
  return pages
}
```

Then you need to invoke this on yourlist in your component's view:

```
var FilteredPages = {
  controller : function(){
    this.filter = ''
    this.index  = 0 
  },

  view : function( ctrl, pageLength, items ){
    return m( '.FilteredPages',
      m( 'input', {
        value : ctrl.filter,
        oninput : function(){
          ctrl.filter = this.value
          ctrl.index  = 0 
        }
      } ),

      m( 'p', 
        m( 'a', {
          innerHTML : 'Back',
          onclick   : function(){
            if( ctrl.index > 0 )
              ctrl.index--
          }
        } ),

        ' ',

        m( 'a', {
          innerHTML : 'Next',
          onclick   : function(){
            var newIndex = ctrl.index + 1

            if( newIndex < items / pageLength )
              ctrl.index = newIndex
          }
        } )
      ),

      m( '.page', 
        items
          // Filter the items according to your requirements
          .filter( function( item ){ return item.includes( ctrl.filter ) } )
          // Paginate the filtered list using our reducer
          .reduce( paginate, [] )
          // Take the page at the current index
          [ ctrl.index ]
            // Map over the items on this page
            .map( function( item ){
              // Produce a view for each item
              return m( 'p', item )
            } ) 
      )
    )
  } 
}
```